# Solr "starts with" search doesn't work -- always treated as "contains"

Tags: search, solr, lucene

When I issue a query (e.g., "ABC*") it seems to ignore the asterisk and just searches the document store for everything containing "ABC" rather than *starting with* "ABC".

I've looked through numerous examples and documentation, but can't seem to determine why Solr searches don't behave the way I think they should.

What am I missing here?

Here is my schema.xml:

```
<schema name="db" version="1.1">
```

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>


<fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>


<fieldType name="integer" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="long" class="solr.LongField" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="float" class="solr.FloatField" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="double" class="solr.DoubleField" omitNorms="true"/>


<fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
<fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

<fieldType name="date" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>


<fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />

<fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>


<fieldType name="textTight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>


<fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer>

    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>

    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />

    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />

    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
            pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"
    />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" class="solr.StrField" />
```

id

name

Comment: In type of questions you need to post your field definition (from schema.xml) and type definition for this field to help you.

Comment: There is no searchapi.xml. Do you mean schema.xml?

Comment: yes, you are too quick , schema.xml

Comment: I have updated the post with my schema.xml

Comment: you need to tell us which field is that you are talking about, i.e what your q=? also tell what is your default field from solrconfig.xml request handler . Is it text?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I'm only searching on the name field. When I changed the type attribute to "text_ws", it behaves closer to the way I expect.

Hopefully this helps some folks out there!